# EF Core with Postgres is generating negative primary keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core with the Postgres provider, each entity has an int primary key with ValueGeneratedOnAdd. This has been working perfectly up until now. Every now and then I nuke my migrations and database and start fresh with `dotnet ef migrations add InitialDb`. After this last refresh my primary keys have started generating from what I assume is int.Min `-2147482647`. They used to start at 1.

I'm not sure what caused this and I would like to go back to having the primary keys increment from 1. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you use attributes like  `[Key]`  and `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` ? Its look like the id's default value have int.MinValue not 0. Try before insert change this value to 0.

Comment: The default value would be an int. Its slightly different to what you have posted above though. I used the fluent API to set it up like this:             builder.Entity<Contract>().Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd(); The strange thing for me is that this has been working all along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something that I changed in the code that caused this behavior. In my base repository when adding a new entity I changed `DbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity)` to `DbContext.Attach(entity).State = EntityState.Added;`

The reason I did this was because when using attach EF will automatically detect existing related entities. Using only add would try and add related entities again whether they already exist in the db or not.

I have no idea why it would suddenly switch to a negative int when generating the ID.

Answer (score 2):

EF Core generates temporary IDs which are then replaced with the real IDs when SaveChanges is called. It's by design behavior.

Comment: This should be the answer.